# PHP_Uml to XMI to UML Diagram on Ubuntu / Linux

Tags: php, uml, pear, phpstorm

I am using the PHP_Uml pear package and I created a XMI in version 1 and 2.
Unfortunately ArgoUml does not parse the XMI 1 correctly, and the XMI 2 always fails with the "new" argo.

```
phpuml . -x 1 -o project.xmi
```

Is there any tool that has the correct UML2, can reverse engineering and, especially, do forward engineering in PHP 5.3 and above?

I would appreciate something that is free or that costs and runs under Linux / Ubuntu (without wine, mono etc.).
I am using phpStorm. That's necessary, because it can't be manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try fully-functional and free 30 day trial of MapForce (http://www.altova.com/mapforce.html). As far as I know, it can convert XMI to UML2 correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/download?pr=phpStorm&updateId=16061) PhPStorm plugin for UML diagrams.